# How to convert a File URL into binary data (multipart/form-data) for upload

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I would like to upload a file from URL using Python requests.post

Would anyone guide me how to convert a file URL into binary data (multipart/form-data) for upload?

I have tried with these code but it return failed.

```
file = requests.get(file_url, stream=True)
file_upload = {
            "name": file_name,
            "uploadfile": file.content 
            }
headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
          }
requests.post('{POST_URL}', files=file_upload, headers=headers)
```

POST_URL is external service and only support PDF file (**string($binary)**).

```
{
    "name": string
    "uploadfile": string($binary) 
}
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per *python-requests* documentation ([Here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file)), if you specify files parameter in `requests.post`, it will automatically set requests content-type as '`multipart/form-data`'. So, you just need to omit the headers part from your post request as:

```
import requests

file = requests.get('{FILE_URL}', stream=True)

with open({TEMP_FILE}, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)

binaryContent = open({TEMP_FILE}, 'rb')

a = requests.post('{POST_URL}', data={'key': binaryContent.read()})
```

> Update: You can first try downloading your file locally and posting its binary data to your {POST_URL} service.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I tried to omit the content-type but I got the error 415 - UNSUPPORTED MEDIA TYPE

Comment: @グエントォ, I have updated my answer, please check if it solves your issue.

Comment: Unlucky me that it still not working. I tried with local file also.

Comment: {POST_URL} service return  {'error': 'bad_request', 'message': 'invalid upload'}

Comment: If possible, can you give the {POST_URL} here for testing?

Comment: It's a commercial service so I can't post it here, I'm so sorry. What is the purpose of totalbits in your answer? I can't see it use anywhere.

Comment: Oh, okay! Totalbits was being used for displaying download progress in the console, but it is not required here, I have removed it. About your issue, what you can do is compare your python request's (headers & data) with the one with Postman request.

Comment: It worked after I follow your answer and remove **"name": file_name** in request body, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear, your issue's resolved. You can go ahead and close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function that can appropriately send your file to any endpoint you want:

```
def upload_file(file_path, token):
"""Upload the file and return the response from the server."""
headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}'}
with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
    files = {'file': (os.path.basename(file_path), file, 'application/pdf')}
    response = requests.post(post_url, headers=headers, files=files)
response.raise_for_status()
return response
```

Python will automatically pick the multipart/form-data content type for you. All you need to do is supply the file correctly. Using the Authorization is optional, but I added it in case the API you want to post to requires one.